# tab order resets in IE 11

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have a div and a button inside it. When the button is clicked, three different buttons show up in the same div.

Navigation using keyboard (Expected): When I tab on the button and hit enter, the three different buttons show up and then when I tab again, the focus should go onto the first of those three buttons. This expected behavior works correctly in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE 11.

In IE 11, when I hit enter on the main button, the tab resets and goes to the first element on the page. And when I tab several times, it follows the whole order and now comes to the first of the three buttons.

```
<div class="blah-list">
        <div *ngFor="let blah of blahs" class="panel panel-default">
            <a href="#/{{blah.id}}" *ngIf="showOption !== blah.id" class="panel-body">
                Hello World
            </a>
            <button *ngIf="showOption !== blah.id" type="button" class="close" (click)="showOption=blah.id" [title]="Options">
                   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical"></span>
            </button>
            <div *ngIf="showOption === blah.id"(clickoutside)="showOption=null">
                <button type="button" class="A" [title]="A"></button>
                <button type="button" class="B" [title]="B"></button>
                <button type="button" class="C" [title]="C"></button>
            </div>
            <button *ngIf="showOption === blah.id" type="button" class="close">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical" (click)="showOption=null"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
```

How can I prevent that from happening? Why does IE behaves differently?

Comment: Because IE sucks.  I'm not really sure I understand... Can you give us the code you're using to do all this?  Or better yet, make a fiddle for us that emulates the behavior.

Comment: Sure. I will update it in couple of minutes